# UIImageView image not being removed when set to nil in uicollectionviewcell

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Basically what I am doing is taking an image of the view, applying a blur to it, and then using that as a blurred uiview overlay in reusable collection view cells in a simple uicollectionview.

```
// Capture Screen for blurr.
-(UIImage *) captureScreen:(CGRect)frame
{
    CGRect grabRect = frame;

    //for retina displays
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(grabRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    }
    else
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(grabRect.size);
    }

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -grabRect.origin.x, -grabRect.origin.y);
    [self.contentView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    viewImage = [viewImage applyBlurWithRadius:1.8f tintColor:nil saturationDeltaFactor:1.0 maskImage:viewImage atFrame:self.imageView.frame];

    return viewImage;
}

// Set blurred image as image view image.
- (void) updateBlur
{
    UIImage* infoViewImage = [self captureScreen:self.infoView.frame];
    self.infoImageView.image = infoViewImage;
}

// Prepare for reuse.
- (void) prepareForReuse
{
    self.infoImageView.image = nil;

}
```

Note the uiimageview is created and added as a subview to the cell's contentView in the initialization. Whenever I scroll slowly this works fine. If I scroll quickly the image will only be removed from the image view sometimes... I am not really sure why this is happening. So far I have tried a number of solutions, even removing the whole uiimageview from the superview and re-initializing/re-adding it as a subview each time but this action has the same issue. Please help!

Comment: How were you able to determine that the image is only removed from the view sometimes?  The `prepareForReuse` method is only called when a cell is taken from the reuse queue in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and presumably you would replace the image with another one at that point.

Comment: I am able to tell by observing the application. There is another image view behind which has another image. Sometimes the image that was most likely in the collection view cell before ends up in my overlaying image view.

Comment: But aren't you always calling updateBlur in cellForRowAtIndexPath?  My point is that setting the `.image = nil` has no effect if you subsequently set `.image = infoViewImage` in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  On the other hand, if you do set `.image = nil`, but don't set `.image = infoViewImage`, then what?

Comment: The image is being given asynch from the the controller in cellforindexpath.

Comment: I see, well that's a whole different can of worms. Without knowing a lot more about your cell structure, and how cellForItemAtIndexPath is configuring the cells, I don't think I can be of much assistance.

Comment: Yep, same here. Any solution? I'm also using AFNetworking to populate the image async, wonder if that has something to do w/it. AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest

Comment: I never did find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the reusable collection view cells are... reusable. You need to implement `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to deal with *every* cell it is *ever* handed, without making any assumptions about whether you may previously have added the subview to it.

Comment: I am not asking a question about how to set up a collection view. The assumption I am asking you to make is that they are set up as re-usable collection view cells. In this case we are looking at the UICollectionViewCell which has a UIImageView that is getting set an image when it is re-used then is having that image removed when it is prepared for re-use. The issue is that the image is not always being removed when scrolling quickly in the prepare for re-use function provided by uicollectionviewcell.

Comment: Yes, and I'm suggesting that `prepareForReuse` might not be the right place to do this and that you should try doing it in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. At least give it a try.